# Did a recent 22.04 update change GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE to =hidden?

Tags: grub2

The `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE` line in my /etc/default/grub recently automagically changed from `=menu` to `=hidden`.
I noticed because the grub2 menu stopped displaying on startup. Something must have made the change and run `update-grub`.
This system has only 22.04 on it. Did some update do this? I didn't. I am the only user of this at-home laptop. I don't have reason to suspect malware. Should I?

Comment: That could be possible. Check your logs (`/var/log/apt/term.log`, `/var/log/apt/history.log`) if the grub-package has been updated. Check also the modification-date of `/etc/default/grub`. If you upgrade via terminal using `apt`, you would be asked if an update would install a new config-file. I'm not sure how other update methods like unattended-upgrades should behave, but I would consider overwriting a config file in `/etc` without asking a bug.